# Merge multiple tables into one row in a new table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

```
UPDATE the_main_table
SET item_Name = (
SELECT item_Name
FROM 1d_high_today
WHERE 1d_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);

UPDATE the_main_table
SET D_high = (
SELECT D_high
FROM 1d_high_today
WHERE 1d_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET D_low = (
SELECT D_low
FROM 1d_high_today
WHERE 1d_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET D_low_volume = (
SELECT D_low_volume
FROM 1d_high_today
WHERE 1d_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET D_high_volume = (
SELECT D_high_volume
FROM 1d_high_today
WHERE 1d_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET D_Margin = (
SELECT D_Margin
FROM 1d_high_today
WHERE 1d_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET D_Volume = (
SELECT D_Volume
FROM 1d_high_today
WHERE 1d_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);

UPDATE the_main_table
SET item_Name = (
SELECT item_Name
FROM 1h_high_today
WHERE 1h_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET H_high = (
SELECT H_high
FROM 1h_high_today
WHERE 1h_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET H_low = (
SELECT H_low
FROM 1h_high_today
WHERE 1h_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET H_low_volume = (
SELECT H_low_volume
FROM 1h_high_today
WHERE 1h_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET H_high_volume = (
SELECT H_high_volume
FROM 1h_high_today
WHERE 1h_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET H_Margin = (
SELECT H_Margin
FROM 1h_high_today
WHERE 1h_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET H_Volume = (
SELECT H_Volume
FROM 1h_high_today
WHERE 1h_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);






UPDATE the_main_table
SET item_Name = (
SELECT item_Name
FROM latest_high_today
WHERE latest_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET l_high = (
SELECT l_high
FROM latest_high_today
WHERE latest_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET l_low = (
SELECT l_low
FROM latest_high_today
WHERE latest_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET L_low_Time = (
SELECT L_low_Time
FROM latest_high_today
WHERE latest_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET L_high_Time = (
SELECT L_high_Time
FROM latest_high_today
WHERE latest_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET L_Margin = (
SELECT L_Margin
FROM latest_high_today
WHERE latest_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);





UPDATE the_main_table
SET item_Name = (
SELECT item_Name
FROM 30m_high_today
WHERE 30m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET T_high = (
SELECT T_high
FROM 30m_high_today
WHERE 30m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET T_low = (
SELECT T_low
FROM 30m_high_today
WHERE 30m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET T_low_volume = (
SELECT T_low_volume
FROM 30m_high_today
WHERE 30m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET T_high_volume = (
SELECT T_high_volume
FROM 30m_high_today
WHERE 30m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET T_Margin = (
SELECT T_Margin
FROM 30m_high_today
WHERE 30m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET T_Volume = (
SELECT T_Volume
FROM 30m_high_today
WHERE 30m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);


UPDATE the_main_table
SET item_Name = (
SELECT item_Name
FROM 5m_high_today
WHERE 5m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET F_high = (
SELECT F_high
FROM 5m_high_today
WHERE 5m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET F_low = (
SELECT F_low
FROM 5m_high_today
WHERE 5m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET F_low_volume = (
SELECT F_low_volume
FROM 5m_high_today
WHERE 5m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET F_high_volume = (
SELECT F_high_volume
FROM 5m_high_today
WHERE 5m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET F_Margin = (
SELECT F_Margin
FROM 5m_high_today
WHERE 5m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
UPDATE the_main_table
SET F_Volume = (
SELECT F_Volume
FROM 5m_high_today
WHERE 5m_high_today.osrs_id = the_main_table.osrs_id
);
```

I have this massive SQL query.

This does preform what I'm trying to accomplish "merge multiple tables columns into new table, within 1 row"

However it is very slow with only a few thousand rows of data.

Is there a way I can shorten this query and still accomplish the same thing?

I have tried things like JOIN & union but have not been able to get them to function properly.

Making this really long query has been the only solution that has actually worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to pore over all your code.  But it is clear from the first few examples that you can use `join`.  For instance:

```
UPDATE the_main_table m JOIN
       1d_high_today ht
       ON ht.osrs_id = m.osrs_id
    SET m.item_Name = ht.item_Name
        m.D_high = ht.D_high,
        m.D_low =  ht.D_low,
        . . .;
```

For this, you want an index on `1d_high_today(osrs_id)`.